# PropertyMetadata to register a DependencyProperty of Type "System.Windows.Point"?

Tags: c#, dependency-properties, createinstance

Here is my code :

```
public class ExoticPoint : DependencyObject
{
    public Point PointValue
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(PointValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PointValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PointValue", typeof(Point), typeof(ExoticPoint), new PropertyMetadata(0));



    public string Description
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Description", typeof(string), typeof(ExoticPoint), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));

    public ExoticPoint()
    {
    }

    public ExoticPoint (string objectName)
        : base(objectName)
    {
    }
}
```

It compiles but when I want to CreateInstance of my type it crashes with the following error :

```
{"Default value type does not match type of property 'PointValue'."}
```

So Im kinda sure the problem is :

```
new PropertyMetadata(0)
```

but as far as I understand PropertyMetadata it should work as there is a Point constructor that takes an int as parameter : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf1b4f2b.aspx

So... what is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right the problem is with the object passed into `PropertyMetada`.The parameter will be the default value for your property so it has to match with the type of your dependency property.

In your case `PointValue` type is `Point` so you should write `new PropertyMetadata(new Point(0))`.

Also your `Description` property which is `string`:  `new UIPropertyMetadata("0")` or `new UIPropertyMetadata("")` depending on your needs.

Comment: I had try new PropertyMetadata(new Point(0)) but it was crashing so I came back. In fact that was crashing because of the String, such a waste of time... :(